# JWT-based authentication for <img> tags?

Tags: html, image, authentication, single-page-application, jwt

Supposed I have a single page application that uses JWT tokens to authenticate against a backend REST api. I transfer the JWT token inside the http header when doing a REST request. So far, so good.

Now, supposed I want to download an image from the server, and I want the image only to be accessible for authenticated users. On the server, this is no problem: Simply define a route that delivers the image, and in that route verify the JWT token.

But: How do I transfer the token from the client to the server? If I use a regular `<img ...>` tag, I can not attach the token as an http header. What should I do?

I basically can think of adding the token, e.g. base64-encoded, to the query string, but that does not seem to be very secure, since the token then appears in the browser's history. On the other hand, I can not think of another approach, without loading images entirely using JavaScript.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i think of Amazon S3 a signed url is what you want here. As you already suggested adding a token to the query string would be fine.

About security: I think this is a matter of the expiration date of the token. As there is no invalidation of the token maybe it is better to use signed URLs:

1. Get a JWT
2. Get a signed URL with that token
3. Use that URL to retrieve the img

This way you can control the expiration of the signed URL independent of the JWT and also define the length of the token used for the signed URL.

Comment: Thank you. But what if the URL was copied by the user and emailed to another, won't the image be displayed then?

Comment: yes, but its like disclosing his credentials, he could give them away as well, same applies for the signed link, also the link will expire at some point.

Comment: How do you do this

Comment: Do you mean the expiry? The Link will only be valid for a predefined time which you usually will set to like 5h, signing a link provides that functionality in S3, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html#private-content-overview-choosing-duration