# Laravel protect images

Tags: laravel, jwt, storage

I have a Laravel application that stores profile images of the users. Currently I store these in the public folder. And I have a HTML & JavaScript for the frontend. The frontend simply uses  tag to link to the profile images. I moved the images to the storage folder and created an API to access them. The API requires JWT so that only logged in users can access the images. But the problem now is that I'm passing the token with the API. Isn't there a better way to let only logged in users access the images and where I can simply use  tag without passing JWT?

I want to protect my images from outside access, yet be able to simply have a link to access them with  tag only for logged in users.

Comment: Which better way are you looking for? Why should providing a token (which is only created for a logged in user) not be enough?

Comment: Also: yes, there might be other ways. Why not use a PHP session, like for other authentication stuff?

Comment: Because passing the token in the url is not secure.

Comment: Then simply do not pass the token in the URL. Usually, you pass such a token in the headers. And through using a session cookie, you would even skip that part

Comment: Could you explain more please. What header if i'm using <img> tag?

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31637180/jwt-based-authentication-for-img-tags (using short-lived URLs), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45454974/get-image-from-authenticated-route (using JS)? If you don't want to try this, why not use session cookies which are automatically sent to the server on each request?

Comment: Thanks. the links are interesting. What about the session cookies, how to use them in this case?